# pandas iterrows problem with a boolean column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a dataframe(10 x 530) which contains a boolean column ['perimeter']. 
When the boolean is False, i need the row to be dropped, so I decided to use the following code:

```
  for idx, data in df5.iterrows():
    if df5['perimeter'] == False:
        df5 = df5.drop(index = idx)
        print('index drop: ', idx)
    elif df5['perimeter'] == True:
        pass
    else:
        pass
```

and I get the following error:

```
    ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: `df5['perimeter]` should be `data['perimeter']`. However, `iterrows` is not recommended in this case. Take a look at `np.where` and `np.select`, where you can actually pass `df5['perimeter']`.

Answer (score 1):

Few things to note:

1. It's generally bad practice to remove items from a collection as you iterate through the collection itself, as indices get missed after a removal.
2. Using `iterrows` in `pandas` is probably a last resort situation as iterative approach in `pandas` is slow.  There's usually a vectorized method or combination thereof that you can utilize instead.

With that said, all you really need here is apply a `mask`:

```
df5 = df5.mask(df5['perimeter'].eq(False).dropna()
```

Or a `loc` on `perimeter=True`:

```
df5 = df5.loc[df5['perimeter'].eq(True)]
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should include what row prompted the error.

Anyhow, notice that you are iterating over the dataframe where each row is stored in the variable `data`. Instead you made comparisons here `if df5['perimeter'] == False` and `elif df5['perimeter'] == True:` using the whole column `perimeter`. That caused the error.
You should write `if data['perimeter'] == False` and so forth.

But, it is bad practice to delete data from an object while iterating over it. Especially when it is that very piece of data you are pointing at. In fact it could often be impossible and cause errors. So you can create an empty DataFrame and only append the rows you wish to keep:

```
empty_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=df5.columns) 
for idx, data in df5.iterrows():
    if data['perimeter'] == False:
        print('index drop: ', idx)
    else:
       empty_df = empty_df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

"When the boolean is False, i need the column to be dropped" I am assuming you mean row as you are only looking at one column in your loop. However, if you already have boolean values then just do boolean indexing and avoid the loop all together:

```
# sample data
np.random.seed(3)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,10).astype(bool), columns=['col'])

# boolean indexing to keep only the true values
df[df['col']]

    col
2  True
3  True
7  True
8  True
9  True
```